# DirectoryServices - find all Windows 7 and Windows 10 computers in domain

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, directoryservices, user-profile

I am creating a tool to delete user profiles by age on all Windows 7 and Windows 10 devices on our domains. I have it working using this filter (`(objectClass=computer)`) but I want to refine to get only Windows 7 and Windows 10 devices because my department manages desktops/laptops not servers. In order to make the tool more efficient and not attempt to connect to devices I don't have admin access to.

So I tried this filter:

```
mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(operatingSystemVersion=*server*))
```

My thought was to do something like this if OS **is not** Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2008, then do something.

I loaded the `operatingSystem` property but can't get it to display. I have tried it in the datagridview and when that didn't work I just tried to do a `Console.WriteLine` and that didn't work either. I want to test my concept before adding the code to use WMI to delete profiles by just displaying the hostname and OS version to make sure it is pulling the information from AD and not giving me servers. Can someone help? Here is the code(I am just working with the v06 domain at the moment):

```
Dim mySearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(enTry)
   mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("dNSHostName")
   mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingSystem")
   mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingSystemVersion")
   mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(operatingSystem=*server*))" '("(objectClass=computer)")

   Dim resEnt As SearchResult
   For Each resEnt In mySearcher.FindAll()
       Select Case dMain
           Case "v06"
               Try

                   hostName = GetProperty(resEnt, "dNSHostName")
                   OSystem = GetProperty(resEnt, "operatingSystem")
                   Dim result1 As Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = ping.Send(hostName, 1000)
                   If result1.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
                       Dim row2 As String() = New String() {hostName, "N/A", OSystem}
                       dgvLocal.Rows.Add(row2)
                   Else
                       My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\ExodusErrorLog.txt", hostName & " - Device is not pingable!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf, True)
                   End If
               Catch ex As Exception
                   My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\ExodusErrorLog.txt", hostName & " - " & ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf, True)
               End Try
           Case "v07.med.va.gov"
       End Select
   Next
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? (what *did* happen?) And what is the code in your `GetProperty` method?

Comment: If you want to filter out os with text `server` in it, you are supposed to use the ldap filter `(&(objectClass=computer)(!(operatingSystem=*server*)))`